# If $f\in \mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n)$ s.t. $\det J_f(x)\neq 0$, why $f(U)$ open for all $U$ open?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in \mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n)$ such that $$\det J_f(x)\neq 0,$$ for all $x$. Why $f(U)$ open for all $U$ open ?

Let $U\subset \mathbb R$ open. Let $a\in U$. By local inversion theorem, I know that there is an open set $a\ni V\subset U$ s.t. $f:V\to f(V)$ is a diffeomorphism, and thus $f(V)$ is open. Unifortunately, I can't do better.

I have as *Hint : If $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $f$ is an open application*. But as I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802021/if-f-in-mathcal-c1-mathbb-rn-mathbb-rn-s-t-det-j-fx-neq-0-for-all/2802027#2802027), $f$ is not necessarily injective, and thus, it's not necessarily a homomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ is locally a diffeomorphism you can write $U$ as a union of open sets $V_a$, $a \in U$, where each $f(V_a)$ is open. Then use
$$f(U) = f( \cup_a V_a) = \cup f(V_a).$$

Answer (score 1):

For each $a \in U$, let $V_a \subset U$ be an open set such that $a\in V_a$ and $f(V_a)$ is open. You've already shown we can always find such a $V_a$. Then $f(U) =\bigcup_{a\in U} f(V_a)$ is a union of open sets and thus open.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in U$. As $\det J_f(x)\ne0$. There is a neighbourhood
$U_1$ of $x$ such that $U_1\subseteq U$ and $f$ maps $U_1$ homeomorphically to an open set $V_1\subseteq \Bbb R^n$. Then $f(x)\in V_1\subseteq f(U)$.
It follows that $f(U)$ is an open set.

Answer (score 0):

For every $y\in f(U)$, there exists $a\in U$ with $f(a)=y$. Then you already know that there exists open $V$ with $a\in V\subset U$ such that $f$ is a diffeomorphism $V\to f(V)$ and hence $f(V)$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$.

Comment: In math this prove that $f(U)$ is open ?